# Flipping elements in Clojure

Tags: clojure, clojure-contrib

If I input a vector and wanted to flip the elements' order, I'd write

```
   (reverse [1 2 3])
```

Now, how would I generalize this idea to be able to input nested vectors and flip the order of elements? Given a matrix A the function should reverse the elements in each column.

Comment: You would also want to reverse nodes? That is: [[1 2 3] [4 5 6]] would be [[6 5 4] [3 2 1]]? Or you only want leaf nodes reversed?

Comment: Inputting the nested vector `[[1 0 0] [0 2 0] [0 0 3]]` would transform to `[[0 0 3] [0 0 2] [1 0 0]]`

Comment: Example and description not clear. The element at the ith row and jth column ends up at which row and column?

Comment: @Alex: Was that supposed to be `[[0 0 3] [0 2 0] [1 0 0]]`? Because I'm not understanding why the 2 would move inside its vector but not anything else.

Comment: If so...use `reverse`.

Comment: Yes, it was supposed to be `[[0 0 3] [0 2 0] [1 0 0]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the example you gave in the comments, this is exactly what `reverse` does given a collection that contains collections. You want `reverse`.